# How to take a user input and post it directly into HTML tags via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, input

I want to take a user input (website address) and have it post directly into an iframe src tag. Can this be done with Javascript or would I have to use something else? Might be a n00b question, but not quite sure where to start.

```
<div id="target">
    <input id="target"></input> <button class="target">Submit</button>
</div>

<div>
    <iframe src="target address goes here from input">
    </iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Javascript can do that, the method is pretty straightforward and obvious:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById("id-of-iframe");
var input = document.getElementById("id-of-input").value;
iframe.src = input;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible (but didnt see without jQuery ;)
But with jquery it's this way

```
$(document).on('keyup', 'input[type="text"'. function(event){

  if(event.keyCode==13){ // Enter Key
    // Validate url

    // Set URL
    $(('iframe').attr('src', $(this).val());
  }

});
```